# send PHP code in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to post php code from my messages table. But it is not posting. For example:

```
<textarea name="update">User can write php codes here for sending</textarea>
<div class="send">Send</div>
```

When i click send button the text code `<?php echo $message;?>` must be in my `messages` table row `post_text` . But post_text is empty, you can see it in the screenshot.

[image]

What is the problem here. What i shoud do to fix this problem? Anyone can help me here ?

```
<?php
include_once '../inc/inc.php';
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

   $update=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['update']);
   if($update){
      $data=$DoDo->InsertText($uid,$update); 
      echo $update;
   }
}
?>
```

InsertText function

```
public function InsertText($uid, $update) {

    $time=time(); 
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    mysqli_query($this->db,"SET character_set_client=utf8") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    mysqli_query($this->db,"SET character_set_connection=utf8") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));

    $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT post_id,post_text FROM `posts` WHERE uid_fk='$uid' order by post_id desc limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

     $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `posts` (post_text, uid_fk,time) VALUES (N'$update', '$uid','$time')") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));

     //The newquery to select for message
     $newquery = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.post_text, M.time,U.username FROM posts M, users U where M.uid_fk=U.uid and M.uid_fk='$uid' order by M.post_id desc limit 1 ") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
     $result = mysqli_fetch_array($newquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     return $result;
}
```

> Note: This problem will be come when i send just php code. If i send
>   normal text then normal text sending from post_text.
>   [image]

I want to send php code like this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: From where do you get the $uid?

Comment: @from inc.php that is loged in uid

Comment: @DevStud the real question here is: "why" do you want to do this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because i need solution. No one can understand my real problem with this question.

Comment: @DevStud You didn't answer my question. In any case, cypherabe's answer is technically correct. If you want to insert "code", you need to wrap it in single quotes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know how to do that. I am trying to make a facebook style wall script. I can not tell every user please use single quotes if you want to share php code. I need real solution.

Comment: @DevStud You'll need to handle that on your side then  and I think you're going about this the wrong way. You're also going to be opening some potentially dangerous doors, since some hackers could easily run an `eval()` on a non-protected db insertion. So, they can do `<?php echo "Hello world";?>` type of stuff, is that it? If so, they can easily run dangerous code in there. I suggest you rethink this. I'm sure even FB doesn't do that. I'm just not grasping the reason for this, since I don't see one that is worth doing, sorry.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tryed `eval()` but not solved problem. Now i have solved with   `encodeURIComponent() `

Comment: @DevStud cool. You know that you can post your own answer and accept it once Stack lets you.

Answer (score 1):

In your update query, you did not check the right variable;

```
$update=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['update']);
   if($update){
      $data=$DoDo->InsertText($uid,$update); 
      echo $update;
   }
```

also in your insert query you have a funny character, remove the **N**

```
VALUES ('$update', '$uid','$time')"

$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"INSERT INTO `posts` (post_text, uid_fk,`time`) VALUES ('$update', '$uid','$time')") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

Do this below

```
    <textarea name="update"><?php echo '<?php echo $message;?>';?></textarea>
```

Comment: that is not a problem. because when i send normal text like `<textarea name="update">Normal Text</textarea>` then it is sending this `Normal Text `from `post_text` row.

Comment: $uid coming from inc.php that is not a problem. Problem is just sending PHP codes. Normal text sending just php code is not sending.

Comment: please check my question i have updated and added another screenshot.

Comment: have you removed the weird N character?

Comment: <?php echo $message;?> is not value user can write another php code here or normal text

Comment: you can use a str_replace then

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 VALUES (N'$update', '$uid','$time')"
```

to

```
VALUES ('$update', '$uid','$time')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead  `if($login){` use  `if($update){`

Answer (score 0):

wait, you literally want the string `'<?php echo $message;?>'` to be inserted, not the value of `$message` ?

if that is the case, you need to either make sure that PHP sees it as a string:

```
<textarea name="update"><?php echo '<?php echo $message;?>';?></textarea>
```

... or maybe it would be enough to post only the code, not the php tags

```
<textarea name="update">echo $message;</textarea>
```

Comment: yes you understand the problem. I want to insert php code like `<?php echo $cypherabe;?>` but it is not inserting. For example when you send php code from facebook wale. That is showing normal text like `<?php echo $cypherabe;?>`

Comment: you need to mask the php tags `<?php ` ... `?>` so that the php interpreter doesn't execute the code. I don't know facebook wale, but I offered two basic methods in my answer